# I have two checkboxes, i need to show or hide one or the other based off my sql value

Tags: php, sql

If the checkbox `['transfer']` is checked which will be the default checkbox that displays on the page, after being saved and the page refreshes they should only have the option to view the checkbox `['reverse']`.

If they select reverse  and save the option for the checkbox `['transfer']` should appear again.

I'm trying to wrap my head around it and it seems really simple but i'm having a block atm.

so i created a variable for my sql query:

```
$secular = sql::value("select * from ev.do.taskAU where event_id = $event_id and transfer = '1'");
```

essentially both checkboxes will have the same field name in the database.. that will be `['transfer']` and it should change based on the bit 0 or 1.

hope that makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what i'm trying:

```
<?php 

$secular = sql::value("select * from event.dbo.taskAU where event_id = $event_id and transfer = '1'");
$checked = $secular['transfer'];

?>

<table><tr>
     <?php if ($checked == 1) echo "<td>Transfer</td><?php if (in_array(login::$id, array('02O','04R','0A3','0BN','0BO','00D','0FR','0E1'))) { echo <td>". cbox_return('transfer') ."</td>"; ?>
     <?php if ($checked == 0) echo "<td>Reverse</td><?php if (in_array(login::$id, array('02O','04R','0A3','0BN','0BO','00D','0FR','0E1'))) { echo <td>". cbox_return('transfer') ."</td>"; ?></tr></table>

</tr></table>
```

Comment: Where are these checkboxes?

Comment: they are in the array, called cbox_return

Comment: And you just want to check them?

Comment: if one is checked and the page reloads they only have the option to use the reverse checkbox. if they check the reverse checkbox.. after it reloads they only have the option to transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the value of whether or not the item was checked from the database, you would use this code:

```
   $checked = ('whatever value you got from the database');

$checkedValOne = (in_array(login::$id, array('02O','04R','0A3','0BN','0BO','00D','0FR','0E1'))) ? true : false;

$checkedValTwo = ($checked == 1 ? true : false;

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo (($checkedValOne && $checkedValTwo) ? "checked" : ""));?>" />
```

The above code will only add `checked` to the checkbox if the value from the database was `1`.

Comment: how do i concat my in array with my if statement above?